# Highcharts Legend titles changing after drilldown and back?

Tags: highcharts, legend, series

I have sample code for question here: http://jsfiddle.net/MuydK/

The problem relates to legend title in the key under chart are changing after I have drilled in and out.

They should stay as 
"actual" and
"target"
And are changing to "series 1" and "series 2".

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
        categories1 = ['1011', '1112', '1213', '1415'],
        name1 = 'Actual',
```

I think I may be missing something in drilldown configuration or setChart code?
I got the same problem with a couple if charts based on code posted above.

Many Thanks

Comment: If you are talking about the legend, which I believe you are doing please update the question so it's easier for other to find a solution with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit2: The problem is in your else statement in the function bellow.

```
click: function() {
    var drilldown = this.drilldown;
    if (drilldown) { // drill down
        setChart(drilldown.name, drilldown.categories, [drilldown.data], drilldown.color);
    } else { // restore
        setChart(name, categories1, [data1, data2], 'white');
    }
}​
```

Instead get rid of `name1 = 'Actual'` and only have `data1` and `data2` and add `name` and `color` to them then you could do like this instead

```
click: function() {
    var drilldown = this.drilldown;
    if (drilldown) { // drill down
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(drilldown.categories);
        setChart([drilldown.data]);
    } else { // restore
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
        setChart([data1, data2]);
    }
}

// add code for removing series
chart.addSeries({
    data
});​
```

I hope you understand, but it will be easier if you build `data1/2`as a highcharts object, and just add the drilldown part to it. So you can change;

```
series: [{
    name: name1,
    data: data1,
    color: colors[0]},
{
    name: name2,
    data: data2,
    color: colors[1]}],
```

to:

```
series: [data1, data2],​
```

Edit: When you are doing operations bellow you should not set redraw to `true`, it will be much faster. The same goes for adding the series. You do not need to call `chart.redraw()` until you have removed and added the charts. And removing stuff is easier backwards. So change:

```
while (chart.series.length > 0) {
    chart.series[0].remove(true);
}
```

To

```
for (var i = chart.series.length; i >= 0; i--){
    chart.series[i].remove(false);
}
// add series with redraw == false
chart.redraw();
```

Comment: Can you update jsfiddle link with chart script and post link, as new to highcharts and not sure where I should add code provided.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you need,

[JSFiddle - Legend Name Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/MuydK/4/)

code:

```
function setChart(name, categories, data, color) {
       console.log(name, categories, data, color);
       chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
       while (chart.series.length > 0) {
            chart.series[0].remove(true);
       }
       for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            chart.addSeries({
                name: name[i],
                data: data[i],
                color: color[i]
           });
      }
 }
```